# I am getting an error while installing nuget package with dotnet ,could not find any project in c:\

Tags: .net, nuget, command-line-interface

I am trying to download packages using dotnet CLI but I am getting an error :
Couldn't find any project in c:...etc
[image: picture]

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are in your solution folder and there is no `.csproj` files inside that folder - you need to `cd` in one more folder which contains desired `.csproj` file for which you want to install nugget package. Not sure that with dotnet CLI you can install package for entire solution.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution I had to access :

```
add webApplication4 add package Newtonsoft.Json
```

```
add <nameOfTheProject> add package <nameOfthePackage>
```